# Converting Total Amount to Separate Bills Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm trying to take an input, convert it to USD, and then have it tell me how many separate bills it is. I have

```
def read_exchange_rates():
    answer={}
    answer['USD'] = 1
    answer['GBP'] = 0.76
    return answer
class Money:

    exchange_rates = read_exchange_rates()

    def __init__ (self, monamount, code):
        self.monamount=monamount
        self.code=code
    def to(self, othercode):
        i = self.monamount/self.exchange_rates[self.code]
        j = i*self.exchange_rates[othercode]
        return j
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.code)+' '+str(self.monamount)
    def bills(self):
        j=self.to('USD')
        hundred=j//100
        return hundred
        jwohundred=j-100*hundred
        return jwohundred
        fifty=jwohundred//50
        return fifty
        jwofifty=jwohundred-fifty*50
        return jwofifty
        twenty=jwofifty//20
        return twenty
        jwotwenty=jwofifty-twenty*20
        ten=jwotwenty//10
        return ten
        jwoten=jwotwenty-ten*10
        return jwoten
        five=jwoten//5
        return five
        jwofive=jwoten-five*5
        return jwofive
        one=jwofive//1
        return one
        jwoone/jwofive-one*1
        return jwooone
        print('The bills/noted for USD'+' '+str(j)+' are:')
        print('USD 100 = '+str(jwohundred))
        print('USD 50 = '+str(jwofifty))
        print('USD 20 = '+str(jwotwenty))
        print('USD 10 = '+str(jwoten))
        print('USD 5 = '+str(jwofive))
        print('USD 1 = '+str(jwoone))
```

If I do a=Money(145.1,'GBP') and then a.bills(), all that is returned is 1.0. It's supposed to return

```
The bills for USD 220.08 are:
USD 100 = 2 
USD 50 = 0
USD 20 = 1
USD 10 = 0
USD 5 = 0
USD 1 = 0
```

What did I do wrong? I know that there's a way to use a dictionary but I couldn't figure out how. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you intend to output the results inside the `bill` function, you should not let it return before it finishes printing. You can return a tuple of all the numbers of bills in the end instead. Also, the values you want are `hundred`, `fifty`, etc., rather than `jwohundred`, `jwofifty`, etc.:

```
def bills(self):
    j = self.to('USD')
    hundred = j // 100
    jwohundred = j - 100 * hundred
    fifty = jwohundred // 50
    jwofifty = jwohundred - fifty * 50
    twenty = jwofifty // 20
    jwotwenty = jwofifty - twenty * 20
    ten = jwotwenty // 10
    jwoten = jwotwenty - ten * 10
    five = jwoten // 5
    jwofive = jwoten - five * 5
    one = jwofive // 1
    jwoone / jwofive - one * 1
    print('The bills/noted for USD' + ' ' + str(j) + ' are:')
    print('USD 100 = ' + str(hundred))
    print('USD 50 = ' + str(fifty))
    print('USD 20 = ' + str(twenty))
    print('USD 10 = ' + str(ten))
    print('USD 5 = ' + str(five))
    print('USD 1 = ' + str(one))
    return hundred, fifty, twenty, ten, five, one
```

Answer (score 2):

When a function hits its return, it's done executing. Only the first statement will be executed here.

If the only thing you care about is the `print` statements at the end, just get rid of the return statements. If you need to return things, you can return them together at the end in a single statement:

```
return jwohundred, jwofifty, jwotwenty, jwoten, jwofive, jwoone
```